# create object of class which is in different project using reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection

I have 2 different project in C#. I am writing code for creating object of class using reflection in 1st project. Now i want to create object of class which is in 2nd project. How can i do that. I am using code like below

```
Type type = Type.GetType("qualified class name");
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
Type objType = obj.GetType();
```

This code is working when i am creating object of class which is in project 1, But when i am creating object of class which is in project 2, **type** is coming null, even i am passing full name like xxx.xx.classname.

Comment: Have you added any ref. of second prject in first project. I am not really C# guy. but still. You check for ref.(if any) to be added in second project for first one

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to reference the .dll of the 2nd project in the first.
Right-Click on the references folder and click 'Add Reference...' then find the compiled dll of the 2nd project and add it.

Comment: Sorry boss it not works, i already have reference on project 2 in project 1.

Comment: Can you not create an object by using the constructor in the normal way rather than using the Activator.CreateInstance(type) etc? - (Also could check the dll is up to date but it probably is)

Comment: No boss, i have to create object by passing class name as string.

Comment: Is the Class is public?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not exactly what you are looking for but I solved my problem by creating the type in the source project and passed the type to the method in another project.

```
    SomeObject.MethodInTargetProject(Type.GetType(FullTypeName));

    public void MethodInTargetProject(Type formType)
    {
        if (newFormType == null)
            return;
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(newFormType);
        ...
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

May be class name whatever you are passing may not be correct... first create a test method and identify the class name as below.

```
string fullName=typeof(YourClass).FullName;
```

then copy the value of "fullName" then use in your code.